# WMIC SoftwareLicensingService setting ProductKey not working

Tags: windows-10, product-key, wmic

When I run this command during a windows modification and reinstall test:

`wmic path SoftwareLicensingService set OA3xOriginalProductKey=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

Its giving me this result:

> Invalid verb switch

What have I done wrong? Is it something silly or what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the
[OEM Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-activation-3?view=windows-11)
key.

Computers shipping with Windows no longer come with a Certificate of
Authenticity attached to the back or bottom of the PC.
Instead, manufacturers have worked with Microsoft to embed
the product key directly into the BIOS or EFI.

In effect, you're trying to access a protected area of the BIOS/EFI,
but `wmic` cannot do it, as this can only be done by some very special API.

The error message "Invalid verb switch" is basically telling you that
your command arguments (switches) are in error : `wmic` cannot set
`OA3xOriginalProductKey`.

Comment: So how would I go about doing this

Comment: This would require creating a program that uses these APIs (which I don't know myself). You could ask the question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where programming questions are treated.

Comment: I know it says avoid thanks... So, Thank You

Comment: You're welcome.